# Unexpected value 'ViewPlayerPagePageModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have created a modal for our view page. once done creating model loads the page its coming blank I Am facing this issue, please try to give a solution. Thank you

this is my tab.page.ts code:

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { ViewPlayerPagePageModule } from '../view-player-page/view-player-page.module';


  @Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
 })
  export class Tab1Page  {


  constructor(public viewCtrl: ModalController,
  public router: Router,  public modalController: ModalController) { }


  async openViewplayerpage() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: ViewPlayerPagePageModule,
  });
  return await modal.present();
 }

 }
```

This is my Appmodule.ts code.i have declared viewpage

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

 import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
 import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
 import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

 import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { ForgotPasswordPage } from './forgot-password/forgot- 
 password.page';
 import { CreateclassPage } from './createclass/createclass.page';
 import { ViewPlayerPagePageModule } from './view-player-page/view- 
 player-page.module';
 @NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent, ForgotPasswordPage, CreateclassPage, 
 ViewPlayerPagePageModule],
 entryComponents: [ForgotPasswordPage, CreateclassPage, 
 ViewPlayerPagePageModule],
 imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
 providers: [
 StatusBar,
 SplashScreen,
 { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
 ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I got this type of error:

```
  Error: Unexpected value 'ViewPlayerPagePageModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. 
  Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
  at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (core.js:39321)
  at Function.get (core.js:39230)
  at getInjectorDef (core.js:455)
  at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.js:17039)
  at core.js:16864
  at core.js:1400
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at deepForEach (core.js:1400)
  at new R3Injector (core.js:16860)
```

Comment: Can you post your AppModule file?

Comment: no now I post my appmodule ts code

Comment: @bjdose thank you, its working now

Answer (score 0):

You're importing your `ViewPlayerPagePageModule` into declarations array of `AppModule` but you need to instead only import it into import array as the other modules.

```js
 // code omitted...
 import { ViewPlayerPagePageModule } from './view-player-page/view- 
 player-page.module';
 @NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent, ForgotPasswordPage, CreateclassPage],
 entryComponents: [ForgotPasswordPage, CreateclassPage],
 imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, ViewPlayerPagePageModule], // <- only import the module here
 providers: [
 StatusBar,
 SplashScreen,
 { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
 ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You only can put modules into import array, because declarations array only accepts components, pipes, and directives.

Comment: last one after import that I getting this error core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.
Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.

Comment: That's related to your ViewPlayerPagePageModule, I think you need to create another post because your first issue was already solved.

Comment: I have posted this ERROR TypeError: ctx.viewpageplayer is not a function.please can you help me.